# EL Capitan and 3-finger selection

Tags: macos, multi-touch

After updating to el capitan I've noticed one annoying problem.

When I select something using 3-fingers gesture I should wait about a second until `cmd + c` copy operation actually copies something to the buffer. If I press `cmd + c` right after I complete selection and release fingers of a trackpad nothing goes to the buffer.

Is it a bug or it's a tweakable behaviour?